# Eliminate Duplication of Table View Elements Upon Scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

Hi I realize that this question has been asked before.  I tried the previous solutions however to no avail unfortunately.  What I am trying to do is to get my UISwitch to appear and not duplicate itself when scrolling on the table view.  This is my current attempt however the UISwitch is not being displayed at all.  Any help as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RestaurantCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    Restaurant *restaurant = [restaurants objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UISwitch *notificationSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(245, 15, 79, 27)];
    [notificationSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:notificationSwitch];

    cell.textLabel.text = restaurant.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = restaurant.hours;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i dont get it, your uiswitch wont display OR your switch displays but its being duplicated, which want do you want?

Comment: updated to show that it works and is displayed but wont remove duplicates

Comment: I see, I have this problems before. but im not on my desk now. i camt send you some snippets. what you need here is to remove the switch from that cell view when you dont wanna display it. ill post the snippets tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

UISwitch `init` Method what say

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

> Parameters
>
> frame

**A rectangle defining the frame of the UISwitch object. The size components of this rectangle are ignored.**

> Discussion

**UISwitch overrides initWithFrame: and enforces a size appropriate for the control**

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RestaurantCell";
        UISwitch *notificationSwitch = nil;
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


            notificationSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            [notificationSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            notificationSwitch.tag = 101;

            cell.accessoryView = switchView;
        }

       if(!notificationSwitch) {
           notificationSwitch = (UISwitch*)[cell.accessoryView viewWithTag:101];

        }
        Restaurant *restaurant = [restaurants objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        switch (indexPath.section) {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel.text = restaurant.name;
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = restaurant.hours;
                break;
            default:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"oh no!";
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately i see where you are going with this but it doesnt display the switch.  Im sure it would work if it was displayed

Comment: you are still not able to see switch?

Comment: no unfortunately the switch does not display :( it displays fine when the switch code is taken out of the if statement

Comment: what is switchView? Thank you for helping!

Comment: UISwitch default size. If we try to give any other size, that will ignored by UISwitch `initWithFrame` method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42728/discussion-between-inovize-and-bhumeshwer-katre)